# how to create a windows explorer folder toolbar from script or program

Tags: toolbar, windows-explorer

In Windows XP, you can create a toolbar by right clicking on the taskbar, and selecting toolbars>new toolbar, then select a folder. A toolbar will be made with the contents of your folder.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? Preferably from a script?

The only documentation I can find on this is about creating a new toolbar, ie a new deskband object, with controls etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about [IShellFolderBand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ShellFolderBand%20Object), but if you look at [this newsgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell/browse_frm/thread/283fc72de129f584?hl=ru&lr&rnum=1&prev=/groups?q=BANDINFOSFB&hl=ru&lr=&selm=ankfbf%2524obl%25241%2540reader08.wxs.nl&rnum=1) you will see that there is no (documented) way to add your IShellFolderBand to explorers band site.

The only alternative I could think of is to implement your own shell extension, it should be pretty easy since all it has to do is create a instance of IShellFolderBand, call IShellFolderBand->InitializeSFB() with a PIDL or IShellFolder and just pass on the other calls to this object (Your shell extension is just a simple proxy)